# How will cursor handle array of input?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, cursor

I have a cursor which selects data from table A left Join Table A, then updates the table A, depending upon the matching criteria.

```
Cursor cur IS
SELECT A.department,
       A.Employee
          FROM A
          LEFT JOIN B
              ON (A.id = B.id)
          WHERE A.date_d  =  GET_Date(B.id, B.date_d);
For Record in cur
update A set ....
.....
END LOOP;
END
```

The function `GET_DATE(id Number, date_d DATE)` will return last year's date (same day of week) from table B corresponding to table A.
For e.g. table A has date 10/30/2015(Fri)  the `GET_DATE` will return 10/30/2015 (Fri) after passing 10/31/2014 from table B.

My Question is the function `GET_DATE` will receive a bunch of dates. 
Will the cursor store each record corresponding to date separately?

Comment: A cursor is just a means of processing the results of a query 1 row at a time.  So if your query returns 99 rows, the loop will iterate 99 times, and in each iteration `Record` will contain the data from 1 of the rows.

Comment: Look at your select statement and the result set it produces carefully. The cursor is just a means of looping through each record of this dataset one by one.

Comment: Note that `GET_DATE` will be called once for each row returned by the cursor before the WHERE clause is considered. So if `SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID` returns 100 rows, `GET_DATE` will be called 100 times. If the `SELECT` above returns 1,000,000 rows then `GET_DATE` will be called 1,000,000 times. Hopefully the basic `SELECT` statement doesn't return too many rows and/or `GET_DATE` is a very efficient function. Best of luck.

Comment: I also note that A is being outer joined to B. What happens if `GET_DATE` is called with both arguments set to NULL?

Comment: @BobJarvis, the Select statement is expected to return more than millions of rows.
I cannot run the function by providing the null values. This is not the same cursor which I am actually running (the actual one is quite complex)

Comment: Because B is outer joined to A there is always the possibility that there will not be a row in B which matches a row from A, which means that the fields from B will be set to NULL in the joined row, and thus `GET_DATE` would be called with NULL arguments. If this is not what you intended you may need to use an INNER JOIN to join B to A. As far as 'millions of rows' being returned, you may need to consider adding a function-based index to B using the `GET_DATE` function, which may help to reduce the query time. Best of luck.

Comment: I ran couple of times the Cursor. I feel it saves records row by row into the cursors and updates the Same way.